# Enzyme Wait for Component to be Fully Rendered

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Currently I'm building a Component that I'd like to test. the component is made up of the following:

```
<Fragment>
    {!error ? (
        <template-that-gets-injected-with-content-if-successful />
    ) : (
        <error-message-goes-here />
    )}
    <noscript>...</noscript>
</Fragment>
```

The component starts off without an error. It has a `useEffect` hook that will make a fetch request, do some data processing, and then update state. If this completes without errors a bunch of content will be loaded in. If there are errors, then it'll fallback to an error message. Then there's the no-script fallback that'll always render.

What I need to be able to do is test the main content (and the error message) with the assurance the component is not loading anymore. This should just be two renders, an initial, and a second at the end of the `useEffect` hook once things are finalized.

```
useEffect(() => {
    try { ... }
    catch (error) {
        console.log('Some Error');
        setError(error);
    }
}, [...]);
```

The problem is that I can't seem to get Enzyme to just hold it's horses and wait. See, if I pass my component a broken mock for fetch (if I were to slip it broken JSON for example) my component will correctly hit the `console.log` statement in the above block but the component that I'm returned does not contain my error message. As in, I haven't been given the component as it would be after `error` is set.

```
test('Error message is shown', (done) => {
    fetchMock.mockResponseOnce(brokenMockData);

    const wrapper = mount(
        <Component />,
    );

    setImmediate(() => {
        console.log(wrapper.debug());
        expect(wrapper.contains(<div>Unknown Error</div>)).toBe(true);
        done();
    });
});
```

The output of `wrapper.debug()` is that of the initial load of the component. Empty template where real content would go if everything is successful and my fallback `<noscript>`. I really need to wait though for that second render.

This would also need to run on all my tests, not just testing the error message. I need to ensure that things settle before checking the content.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. For whatever reason, if I expand the ternary so that it's either my component, error, or the fallback, everything works. Having the fallback always there was a problem.